# MS Access - Add buttom on every row

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to do something like the one the image in access. I have a form for sales and in it a subform with itens, and i would like to have a delete and edit every row so the user can delete a specific item.

[image]

can someone help me?

Comment: Then you have to use `Continuous Form` instead of subform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the record with the button clicked becomes the *current record*, all you need is this code line:

```vb
Private Sub YourDeleteButton_Click()

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
    
End Sub
```